Why does my data collected for wing area vs. horizontal displacement not correlate with known theory?
Based on my research, as the wing area of a glider increases, so should the flight distance. However, as you can see from the screenshot below, 
The flight distance generally decreases when the wing area is increased. (I did 7 different wing areas and 5 trials for each wing area so 35 trials total, the data points in the picture are the averages.)
For context, this is for my IB Physics HL IA, and I was told that I need to find a positive linear relationship between the two variables. Is this necessarily true? Or can I have data that is negatively linear but then I justify it in my analysis? Theoretically, my experiment should have a positive linear relationship since I change the wing area and then measure the corresponding flight distance.
I have kept the following variables constant:
Weight of the glider at 27g
Launch angle from the ground at 8º, since I used a wooden platform with a thick rubber band.
Launch force of 30N
Windless sports hall
Aspect Ratio of 5
Please help me figure out what is going wrong, and how I should proceed. Thank you very much. I am a first-timer on aviation stack exchange so I hope my question makes sense.

Yes please, I would certainly appreciate enlightenment on the theory.

How did you get those points? Are they based on some real data, simulations or on simple estimations?

What else changed as the wing area increased? Weight? Frontal area? Aspect ratio? Center of Gravity? Many relationships apply when all else remains the same; when all else doesn't remain the same, then you can have competing influences at work, and your results are the sum of all the effects, not just the one that you're most interested in.

Let's see...  mass is 27grams, starting launch force is 30Newtons.  Hmmm....

I kept aspect ratio constant, weight constant, everything constant, except that the ratio of the wing area to the fuselage length and tail length changed...although I don't know what that does

@ThomasPerry...uhm are you trying to say that the force is too great for the mass?

@sophit, they are based on real data. I made the wood balsa glider myself and actually flew it in a real sports hall in real life.

Well, then post some pictures

@Midnightakatsukireborn Doing the math F=ma, the resulting a seems a bit unrealistic. My initial reaction was Wow!  That leaves me wondering if I have misunderstood something, or if there was a conversion error in the experimental data reading/reduction process.  As I recall, 1 Newton is equal to the force needed to accelerate 1 kg through 1 meter in 1 second, per second.  Your comments have been very helpful, indeed.  I surmise your y variable is distance, x is wing area...  no? An interesting investigative experiment and question that you have posed. Nice!

Yep, 30 Newtons looks ok, I think.

Yes, y variable is distance, and x variable is wing area! I'm sorry that I did not make it clear in the graph. Thank you for your encouragement and the comment to digiovanni, you guys are really awesome

Also, @sophit, sure, I'll post!

If one keeps the launch angle and force constant and increases wing area, the tendency will be for the model to fly higher, then stall, leading to a shorter gliding distance.
Hand launching gliders for distance from the ground is an art unto itself.
To better understand gliding, one may be way better off launching them from the grandstands rather than the floor so the model can reach steady state airspeed, where airfoil lift/drag properties can be studied.
Here you will find that optimal wing area corresponds to best angle of attack from the lift equation:

weight = lift = $\rho$ × area × V$^2$× coefficient of lift

Angle of attack is part of coefficient of lift.
If the wing is too large, lower angle of attack (for the same lift) will be less efficient and drag will be higher.  If the wing is too small, higher angle of attack will again be less efficient.
This relationship can also be studied based on airspeed, again by varying pitch settings.  Each wing will have an optimal L/D ratio, which gives the longest glide$^2$.
Keep weight constant, and adjust elevator trim (pitch) for larger and smaller wings accordingly.
For a given weight and airfoil type, an optimum size should give the longest glide$^1$.
$^1$ Reynolds number is also an important consideration.  Smaller, slower model airfoils will have different lift/drag performance characteristics as compared with faster full scale wings
$^2$ This data will make for some great graphs!

Hey, thanks a lot!! I think I have a better understanding now. Do you think I should redo the experiment to fly it from a grandstand or some kind of elevation? Also, just to clarify, I used a launcher (platform with rubber band, sloping upwards at 8º, and the rubber bands act kind of like a catapult). I did not hand launch. Thanks a lot again! Also, for your footnotes, do you mean the data I already have? If so then I'll happily continue writing my IA :))

@Midnightakatsukireborn yes, gently hand launching it (as close to its flying speed as possible) from elevation.  You may find that it is important to scale the tail to the larger wing.  As your technique improves, relative standard deviation for your flights will get better.  Catapult launched "free flight" gliders (uncontrolled) have many variables, ones dropped or gently launched from elevation quickly settle in to their flying speed (if they are staticly stable).

Another reference: for static stability

Ah, I see. However, I don't have the time to improve my hand-throwing technique, I need to write about the variables that I kept constant so...it will be pretty hard to convince IB that I was able to throw the glider without any human error (in any case I can't quantify human error). Dropping it seems like a good idea, but my sports hall has no area where I can drop it from, It's just flat ground with 4 walls and that's it. I can't experiment in the open otherwise there's too much wind. But thanks for the enlightenment!

@Midnightakatsukireborn You've made a good effort! Your experiment appears to be supported by your results.  Use your best form in the write up.  Nothing seems wrong with your hypothesis and consequent data.  Like most experiments, there is always concern something is wrong.  But you've checked, and re-checked, and thought-it-through... Remember to comment regarding possible sources of error, and consequent limitations in your results. DiGiovanni thinks much better on the right track about these things...
